# Como superponer dos imagenes en CSS y que respeten el tamaño de un DIV

Tags: css, bootstrap, css3

tengo un problema de diseño, estoy intentando super poner dos imagenes para hacer el típico efecto que al pasar el puntero aparezca la imagen que está por debajo, pero a la hora de colocarles las propiedades de style: absolute, estas se salen de su DIV principal y no respetan su tamaño, si alguien me pudiese ayudar, estaría muy agradecido, adjunto imagenes y código.

 Asi es cómo se ve sin las propiedades, como veís las imagenes respetan el tamaño del DIV:
[image: Asi es cómo se ve sin las propiedades, como veís las imagenes respetan el tamaño del DIV]

Y así se ve cuando les añado las propiedades del position absolute:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es este: (Sin añadir las propiedades):

```
echo "<div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4 mb-4' data-aos='fade-up'>
      <div class='block-4 text-center border'>
        <figure class='block-4-image'>
          <a href='producto/".$fetchedQuery[$c]['product_id']."'><img src='".$fetchedQuery[ ['product_imagen']."' alt=".$fetchedQuery[$c]['product_name']." class='img-fluid'><img src='/Carrito/images/blog_1.jpg' alt=".$fetchedQuery[$c]['product_name']." class='img-fluid'></a>
</figure>
<div class='block-4-text pb-4 px-4'>
  <h3><a href='producto/".$fetchedQuery[$c]['product_id']."' class='bg-dark text-white d-block border py-1' style='border-radius: 7px'>".$fetchedQuery[$c]['product_name']."</a></h3>";
  if ( $fetchedQuery[$c]['discount'] != 0 ) {
  echo "<h4><span class='badge badge-pill badge-info' id='available' style='position: absolute; top:10px; right: 25px; display: block;'> ¡En Oferta! </span></h4>   
  <p class='text-primary font-weight-bold'><strike> Antes: $".number_format($fetchedQuery[$c]['product_price'])."</strike><br> Ahora: $".number_format($fetchedQuery[$c]['product_price'] - ($fetchedQuery[$c]['product_price'] * $fetchedQuery[$c]['discount'] / 100))."</p><a href='producto/".$fetchedQuery[$c]['product_id']."'><button class='btn btn-sm btn-dark btn-block'><span class='icon icon-shopping-bag mr-2'></span>Ir a Comprar </button></a>";
} else {
echo "<h4></h4><p class='text-primary font-weight-bold'> Precio: $".number_format($fetchedQuery[$c]['product_price'])."<br>Costo Fijo</p> <a href='producto/".$fetchedQuery[$c]['product_id']."'><button class='btn btn-sm btn-dark btn-block'><span class='icon icon-shopping-bag mr-2'></span>Ir a comprar </button></a>";
 }

echo "</div>
</div>
 </div>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías tener el `<div>` que envuelve la imagen con un `background-image` y luego la propia imagen. Así cuando ocultes la imagen se verá la que hay en el **background**.

Para ocultar la imagen podrías hacerlo a través de un `@keyframes` para mejorar el efecto.

```css
.contenedor {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/600x315/ac/b5/ec/acb5ec60dcd5c8f050394ec319c85806.jpg');
}

.contenedor:hover img {
  animation-name: desvanecer;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes desvanecer {
  from {opacity: 1;}
  to {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <img src="https://www.infovet.es/imagenipequena-veterinario-Bajadas-de-glucosa-en-el-gato-Qu-e-hago--153.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Al agregar `position:absolute` en algun elemento, ademas deberias incluir:

- Agregar al menos `width: 100%`, o `left` y `right` en dicho elemento, ya que al ser absolute ya no tiene referencias de anclado de bloque (ej: en `<div class='block-4-text pb-4 px-4' style='position:absolute'>`).
- Agregar `position: relative` en el contenedor padre del elemento, para que quede relativo a este. Los valores `left` `right` `top` `bottom` seran relativos a este elemento.

Intenta